# How can I optimise my SQLAlchemy instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to fetch a fair amount of data. Without going into gratuitous detail, we have a Deliveries table that links through to several other tables, which then link to more tables. I need to access data from all these linked tables to create a delivery JSON file.

Currently, it's running extremely slowly in the way I'm accessing the elements. Does anyone have any advice (either specific or general) to improve performance? The code accessing it is below, I would add all the table definitions but they're rather large. The definitions of the tables are all standard, without lazy being set on them or anything.

```
# Get the deliveries for the specified date
    delivery_rs = session.query(Delivery).join(Order) \
        .filter(and_(Delivery.DespatchDateTime.between(start_date, end_date), Order.ProductionSite == site_map.get(site))).all()
    # Setup our rowcount for the metadata later
    rowcount = 0

    # Go through each delivery in the resultset, formulate the full job/delivery/client/customer data and add it to the data array
    for delivery in delivery_rs:
        # Add to our rowcount
        rowcount = rowcount + 1

        # Add the jobs to our job array
        job_deliveries = delivery.JobDeliveries
        jobs = []
        quantity = 0
        for job_delivery in job_deliveries:
            job = job_delivery.Job
            web_ref = job.ClientJobReference
            if web_ref and not re.match(r'^CCW_', web_ref):
                web_ref = "" 
            elif web_ref:
                web_ref = re.sub(r'^CCW_', '', web_ref)
            jobs.append({
                "web_ref":      "CCW_{}".format(web_ref) if web_ref else "",
                "name":         job.JobName,
                # The artwork is stored in S3, so provide a link
                "thumbnail":    "https://example.com/{}.png".format(web_ref) if web_ref else ""
            })

            quantity = quantity + job_delivery.Quantity

        # Format our delivery data
        if delivery.AddressContact:
            address_contact = delivery.AddressContact
            contact_data =  {
                        "title":    title_map.get(address_contact.Title),
                        "name":     address_contact.ContactName,
                        "email":    address_contact.ContactEmail,
                        "phone":    address_contact.ContactNumber
                    }
        else:
            contact_data = {}
        
        order = delivery.Order
        client = order.Client
        delivery_method = delivery.DeliveryMethod
        address = delivery.Address
        
        result["data"].append(
            {
                "order_number": order.OrderSequenceId,
                "quantity":     quantity,
                "method":       delivery_method.Name,
                "client":       client.Name,
                "end_client":   client.EndCustomer,
                "jobs":         jobs,
                "contact":      contact_data,
                "address": {
                    "business": address.BusinessName,
                    "postcode": address.PostCode,
                    "town":     address.Town,
                    "county":   address.County,
                    "country":  address.Country.Name,
                    "lines": [
                        address.AddressLine1,
                        address.AddressLine2
                    ]
                }
            }
        )
```

I haven't tried all that much as there's a lot of info on optimising SQLAlchemy out there, but I'm unsure of what would actually help in my scenario. It's taking 15 seconds to gather the data for about 100 deliveries (most have multiple jobs in them). i did try joining every table onto the query but it just returned no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-loading/Eager-loading all the related data will probably help a lot with the performance.  Otherwise every time you access a relationship that is not loaded then another query is executed.

[relationship-loading-with-loader-options](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#relationship-loading-with-loader-options)

In your example it might look something like this (**UNTESTED**) with SQLAlchemy 2.0 `select` style querying:

```py
    from sqlalchemy.sql import select
    q = select(Delivery).join(Order).where(and_(Delivery.DespatchDateTime.between(start_date, end_date), Order.ProductionSite == site_map.get(site)))
    q = q.options(
        # We are already doing a join, so just use that join to load in the related orders and then join again to get those clients.
        joinedload(Delivery.Order).joinedload(Order.Client)
        # Load all these separately.
        selectinload(Delivery.DeliveryMethod),
        selectinload(Delivery.Address),
        selectinload(Delvery.AddressContact),
        # But here get this association object and the job too.
        selectinload(Delivery.JobDeliveries).joinedload(JobDelivery.Job)
        )
    delivery_rs = session.scalars(q).all()
```

It is hard to tell what is a class, what is a relationship and what is a value because it seems like everything is named with CamelCase so I'm not sure I got this correct.

To check that you got all the relationships you can turn on `echo=True` and start your script.  All the queries should happen up front and not inside your for loop.  You could put a print statement or something in it.